# Android socket.io https not connecting

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I have an Android application which is communicating with a web-service. Before adding `SSL` on the web-service, we used `http` protocol to communicate. Everything went fine.

The web-service enabled SSL, and now the client cannot communicate with the server. It does not connect.

```
// Method to create the socket
private Socket initSocket() throws Exception {
   IO.Options op = new IO.Options();
   try {
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

      HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
          @Override
          public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
              HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
              boolean result = hv.verify(hostname, session);
              return result;
          }
      };

      op.hostnameVerifier = hostnameVerifier;
      op.sslContext = sslContext;
      op.secure = true;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

   op.timeout = SOCKET_TIMEOUT;
   op.reconnection = true;
   op.reconnectionAttempts = 2;
   op.reconnectionDelay = 2000l;
   op.reconnectionDelayMax = 5000l;

   Socket socket = IO.socket(URL, op);
   return socket;
}
```

Creating the socket and connecting to the server:

```
// Try to connect to the socket
Socket socket = initSocket();
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Connecting);
            }
 }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Connected !);
            }
 });

 socket.connect();
```

Calling `socket.connect();` will try to connect to the web-service, but it hangs there. There are no error messages, no exceptions. The only debug messages what can I see in the console is: `"Connecting"`, from the socket's callback. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I really don't know how I fixed this, but try to establish a secure https connection between mobile and your server. Check if you can access the web service through a web client. If it doesn't connect it means that the secure connection can't be made (maybe mismatched/placed/configures ssl certificate on backend side).

Comment: I can't solve this problem. How did you create https connection in android and your server?

Comment: 1st enable https on your backend side. Check if you can connect, make request from a debug terminal/software (like postman) and if everything is working then you should setup https on your mobile and connect with your server.

Comment: @ I set https and work with postman. but not work with android :-(